# How do I send images and javascript files to the browser using Node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, http-status-code-404

I have created a Node.js server that worked well when the Javascript was part of the HTML page. I moved the JS to another file and added some images. Now it won't load the images or the JS into the browser. However, the web page renders perfectly when I open the web page directly. This is what my server looks like:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.end('Hello World!Go to /map to see the google map');
});
app.get('/map',function(req,res){
    var conn;
    //images must be sent to the client from the server...
    res.sendfile(__dirname+'/client/google_maps.html');
    //receiving requests from jQuery 
});
```

I am not using the Express project structure or the Express middleware or Express configuration to do this.

Comment: What does "However, the web page renders perfectly when I open the web page directly." mean, in contrast to what you wrote before that? It looks like you don't have routes defined for the images and JS files, but only for the HTML file.

Comment: Also, you may want to remove `var conn;` from this example, as it's not used and only clouds the picture.

Comment: Consider using the express/connect `static` middleware to serve your static files: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html

Comment: @dimadima I meant when I right click on the file and say `Open in Google Chrome` it works.And when I created the server I was still testing the code and had not added any images or refactored the `js`into a seperate file

Comment: When you right click and open the file in Google Chrome, the file isn't served by Node.js, it's served by your filesystem (note the url is like `file://`). When serving the files with your Node server, you need add routes for the files your factored out, like I mentioned in the above comment-- either manually with `app.get()`, or with the `static` middleware.

Comment: When you server the file from your filesystem, your browser asks the filesystem for the JS file and images, and you filesystem obliges. But you don't have routes for the JS and images in your Node server, so your Node server doesn't know how to serve those images. So it 404s, since none of the routes it knows about match the request.

Comment: @dimadima `static` works and is awesome,thanks for taking the time for explaining stuff,one last thing I would like to know,does the `browser` send additional `requests` to the `server` for each of these files and how can I handle those without using `express`.

Comment: Yep, your browser sends a request for each file that is referenced by index.html. To serve these without Express/Connect, take a look at https://github.com/substack/substack.net/blob/master/server.js#L40-L112. The code in that repository runs http://substack.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's all your code, I think the problem you met is reasonable. You didn't tell your server how to respond your images and scripts when browser requested. For example in your `google_map.html` file you have `<script src="myjs.js"></script>`, then your browser will ask your node application to give the content of `myjs.js` but your server don't know how to deal with it.

You could try to add code like below to see if it helps.

```
app.get('/myjs.js', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/myjs.js');
});
```

As dimadima said, Express provides a module to handle static files that you can use like

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```